# Identifying a statistical formula

Tags: normal-distribution

Going through some old notes of mine, I found a formula whose purpose seemed statistical, but whose provenance and use I have dumbly forgotten to write. I am asking if anybody might remember this one:

\begin{align*}
-N-\frac1{N}\sum_{j=1}^N (2j-1)(A_j+B_j),
\end{align*}
where
\begin{align*}
A_j=\ln\left(\frac{1}{2}+\int_{\bar{x}}^{x_j} \exp\left(-\frac{(t-\bar{x})^2}{2s^2}\right)\mathrm{dt}\right)
\end{align*}
and
\begin{align*}
B_j=\ln\left(\frac{1}{2}-\int_{\bar{x}}^{x_{N-j+1}} \exp\left(-\frac{(t-\bar{x})^2}{2s^2}\right)\mathrm{dt}\right)
\end{align*}

and where $x_j,\quad j=1\dots N$  is given data, $\bar{x}$  is the mean, and $s$ is  the standard deviation.

Can anybody help?

Comment: could you please check if the formula is ok? I tried to reflow your formula, since he original version did not fit in the page, but had some problems with MathJax, so I ended up splitting it.

Comment: Yeah I think so @mpiktas; thanks for splitting, and apologies for the inconvenience.

Comment: I'm pretty sure some normalizing constants are missing from the integrals: you need to divide them by $\sqrt{2\pi}s$.

Answer (score 4):

When correctly rewritten (as indicated in a comment), it will be the [Anderson-Darling](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Anderson%E2%80%93Darling_test) statistic (for a normality test).